# Jquery live search and checkbox filter, grid

Tags: jquery

I'm searching for a way to have a live search of my grid + checkboxes to filter. I have a grid with students (photo & name). What I would like is to have checkboxes, which filters the different classes the students are in. and a search bar where I can type a student name.

I have both elements working, a search bar and checkboxes to filter. But they don't work together.

When I type peter it shows peter like I want to but when I check A I see all students from class A. Ofcourse I should still see just peter.
When I uncheck A nothing is shown. What can I do to let the two work together?? See my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wpxajkcw/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter").keyup(function () {

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $("li").each(function () {

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut(0);

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
        $('.studentList > li').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class on already hidden students and exclude from show behavior:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter").keyup(function () {

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $("li").each(function () {

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hidden');

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
        $('.studentList > li').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).not('.hidden').show();
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wpxajkcw/

To resolve unchecking cehckbox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {

        if($('div.tags').find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
        $('.studentList > li').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.studentList > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).not('.hidden').show();
        });
        } else {
            $('.studentList > li').not('.hidden').show();
        }
    });
});
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wpxajkcw/1/

Comment: That is working, one little question about the checkboxes. when i check A and uncheck it again. nothing is displayed. And i would like every thing to displayed when nothing is checked. Is that possible?